# Git site deployment - checkout in post-receive hook not working

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout, git-post-receive

I've followed this tutorial ['Using Git to manage a web site'](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto), using Tower to commit and push my local repo to the remote server. Pushing succeeds with the following message:

```
Pushing to ssh://user@mysite.com/~/git/tprevo.git
stdin: is not a tty
Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 171.95 KiB, done.
Total 40 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://user@mysite.com/~/git/tprevo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> production
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/production/production'

Successfully created tracking connection.
```

I've verified that my post-receive hook is executing, but the `checkout` command doesn't add the pushed code into what I believe I've set up as my working directory. I've been trying to figure this out all day.

**post-receive:**

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/tprevo/public_html/tprevo git checkout -f
```

I'm new to Git and very keen to learn. What's the best way to debug this?

Comment: Did you check the permission on `/home/tprevo/public_html/tprevo` ? It should be writable by the user that you ssh into.

Comment: Yes it's writable, I've temporarily set it to 777 but the files are never checked out to that path. Wouldn't there be an error message if the path was not writable?

Comment: `/home/tprevo/` and `/home/tprevo/public_html` need at least `111` (`a+x`) as well.

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid. What I'm looking for are some checks to place in my post-receive hook so I can work out where this is falling over, instead of it just failing quietly.

Comment: Ahh ... Do you have multiple branches? I see production on the remote side ... try changing your hook to specify the branch you want to force ... IE git checkout -f production

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay ... I've got a similar setup ... is your file executable? 
Please check the files attributes ...

```
ls -la post-receive
```

If it's not executable then you need to chmod it ...

```
sudo chmod +x post-receive
```

UPDATE

Noticing that you have a named branch you may want to be specific in the checkout command for your post-receive hook ...

```
git checkout -f production
```

Comment: That was it - I wasn't specifically checking out the 'production' branch. I'm very happy with this setup, dead simple to deploy to my dev and production environments. Thank you so much!

Comment: do you know why that `stdin: is not a tty` appears?